# Youtube embedded video inside animate.css classes not showing properly

Tags: css, youtube, css-animations

When clicked on Full Screen view inside the embedded Youtube player the whole page goes into full screen mode like what happens when we press F11 (key), this problem is only happening in chrome and only when i have added animate.css classes `animated` and the effect class like `fadeInDown` please check the below code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 delay-2 animated fadeInDown">
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/EqDxIJ42zHg?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

.delay-2 { // If in case...
    -webkit-animation-delay: 600ms;
    animation-delay: 600ms;
}
```

I have searched the web but did't find any solutions, i think this is to do with the CSS animation properties. How can I rectify this issue? have any body came across such issue ?

Thanks.